# Wrapping Text around a carousel

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm a first year student using Bootstrap 4 on a little website project. Like the title said, I am trying to wrap text around a carousel. I already kinda made it but it's really weirdly pushing the text down when sliding to the next image. I really don't know how to prevent this from happening.

I didn't use the column system from Bootstrap as I want the text to be around the carousel and not next to it. Using float works but it still pushes the text down when sliding to the next image.

Anyways, here's my code:

```
  <main class="p-5 justify-content-center">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Zurück</a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="float-right">
            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- The slideshow -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="imgs/mallorcaBild1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="imgs/mallorcabild2.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="imgs/mallorcabild3.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Mallorca</h1>
        <h3 class="text-secondary">Mallorca bietet wunderschöne Strände mit einem traumhaften türkisen Meer.
        </h3>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil ad, ex eaque fuga minus
            reprehenderit asperiores earum incidunt. Possimus maiores dolores voluptatum enim soluta omnis
            debitis quam ab nemo necessitatibus.</p>

    </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by giving the carousel a custom sized container. This will make the sliding animation stay inside the container/carousel.